# Splitting large files in half

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, split, command

**tl;dr:** I need a way of splitting 5 GB / ~11m row files in ~half (or thirds) while keeping track of exactly every file I create and of course not breaking any lines, so I can process both files at once

I have a set of 300 very large json-like files I need to parse with a php script periodically. Each file is about 5 GB decompressed. I've optimized the hell out of parsing script and it's reached it's speed limit. But it's still a single-threaded script running for about 20 hours on a 16 core server.

I'd like to split each file into approximately half, and have two parsing scripts run at once, to "fake" multi-threaded-ness and speed up run time. I can store global runtime information and "messages" between threads in my sql database. That should cut the total runtime in half, having one thread downloading the files, another decompressing them, and two more loading them into sql in parallel.

That part is actually pretty straight forward, where I'm stuck is splitting up the file to be parsed. I know there is a `split` tool that can break down files into chunks based on KB or line count. Problem is that doesn't quite work for me. I need to split these files in half (or thirds or quarters) cleanly. And without having any excess data go into an extra file. I need to know exactly what files the `split` command has created so I can note easy file in my sql table so the parsing script can know which files are ready to be parsed. If possible, I'd even like to avoid running `wc -l` in this process. That may not be possible, but it takes about 7 seconds for each file, 200 files, means 35 extra minutes of runtime.

Despite what I just said, I guess I run `wc -l file` on my file, divide that by *n*, round the result **up**, and use split to break the file into that many lines. That should always give me exactly *n* files. Than I can just know that ill have `filea`, `fileb` and so on.

I guess the question ultimately is, is there a better way to deal with this problem? Maybe theres another utility that will split in a way thats more compatible with what I'm doing. Or maybe there's another approach entirely that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem.  If you have 300 such files, why not just load them in parallel?  From what you describe, I don't see a need to break apart individual files.

Comment: you have 300 files of 5GB each... as JSON? And you can load it in PHP?

Comment: Does split -n not work for you? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

Comment: ```I've optimized the hell out of parsing script and it's reached it's speed limit. But it's still a single-threaded script running for about 20 hours on a 16 core server.``` - you've reached the limits of PHP, please rewrite that specific part in C++ and just have php script call your c++ program via shell_exec() or whatever.

Comment: each file are 5GB individually? you shouldn't have to chop up 5GB, you should be able to just load 1-file-at-a-time and make sure php clears memory before loading the next file - sure it will use more than 5GB RAM at runtime, but a 16C server probably has plenty of ram anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I wait for them all to download before I start processing them, there goes any speed boost I'd get by processing them in parallel.

Comment: @Joni `-n` would be ideal! Sadly the `split` in my OS has far fewer options than yours.

Comment: @hanshenrik Shockingly, "learn C++ and write part of the script in that" is not a workable solution.

Comment: @hanshenrik I'm not splitting the file because 5 GB it "too big" for php. My script does just fine reading 128 KB at a time. I want to split it in half so I can run two processing scripts at once, and cut the processing time in half.

Comment: @l008com oh, proc_open & co then

Comment: Which OS are you using? If you can't find a precompiled GNU coreutils package for your OS (which includes `split`) you can compile it from source https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it wasn't easy to find a solution.

First you need to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to convert your JSON to string format.

Then use the GNU version of `split`, it has an extra --filter option which allows processing individual chunks of data in much less space as it does not need to create any temporary files:

```
split --filter='shell_command'
```

Your filter command should read from stdin:

```
jq -r '' file.json | split -l 10000 --filter='php process.php'
```

`-l` will tell `split` to work on 10000 lines at a time.

In `process.php` file you just need to [read from stdin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) and do whatever you want.